# ABPeoplePickerView Warning NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, addressbook, abpeoplepickerview

Using Mac OS 10.8.3 and xCode 4.6.1 and using ABPeoplePickerView with a very simple Cocoa App with  XIB using ABPeoplePickerView results in an run time warning coming from ABPeoplePickerView:

*2013-04-02 21:58:36.848 AddressbookTest[4462:303] *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.*

but I cannot change a class crCeated by Apple itself. A Apple bug? Any workaround to avoid this or simple ignore the runtime warning?

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore it. If you want to harass the Address Book team about it, use bugreport.apple.com, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Any idea why this is just showing up in 10.8.3?  Found the same thing in WebKit.

Comment: Not offhand. Someone not paying attention I guess.